# Applet error in Java Console

Tags: java, file, security, applet, accesscontrolexception

```
CacheEntry[http://localhost:8080/CreateDPdf/CreatePdf.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Tue Jul 07 21:15:58 IST 2015,length=8112
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "Report.pdf" "write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at createpdf.CreatePdfApplet.jButton_pdfActionPerformed(CreatePdfApplet.java:119)
    at createpdf.CreatePdfApplet.access$100(CreatePdfApplet.java:21)
    at createpdf.CreatePdfApplet$2.actionPerformed(CreatePdfApplet.java:84)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can run my applet but I am not able to create a PDF file from the input text area after a button click. I am using iTextPDF.

Comment: Wooooooah, could you do a little formatting? What are you trying to do? what code is causing the problem? Give us some meat here.

Comment: I can able to create applet and run, I have jtextArea to write the words or sentence from that I want to create pdf file by clicking button but some "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "Report.pdf" "write") how to solve that II am using itextpdf to create applet

Comment: this looks like a file permission problem. Are you sure you have write permission on your pdf files?

Comment: In my applet creation program I have created jar file and In that program I am able to write the words via text area and can create pdf in folder named "Report.pdf" and I add that jar file in web application and run the web application to run the applet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to sort out my problem by adding following codes to my 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\security\java.policy`

```
grant codeBase "http://localhost/-" {
 permission java.security.AllPermission;
 permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";
 permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "write";
};
```

Comment: An applet that requires access to the local file system on the client computer needs to be **digitally signed** using a valid code signing certificate.  Editing policy files is something that will only work for the developer's machine.

Comment: But how to be digitally signed using a valid code signing certificate

Comment: That is too big a question to answer in a comment.

Comment: any other resource for get it done. any example how to do that.